# Control of 4 pin cpu fan with 3 pin socket and ...?

Tags: 12v, fan, speed, motor-controller

I have a problem with controlling my cpu fan speed since it has a 4 pin connector and the socket on my motherboard is broken (transistor connected to it has burnt).

I have it connect at the moment to 3 pin socket but I would like to reduce its speed somehow. I know I can apply a  transistor or a potentiometer on the 12V rail that goes to the fan but is that a good idea or you have anything else to suggest to me ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A quick search led me to [this](http://www.pavouk.org/hw/fan/en_fan4wire.html):

> **Sense (tachometer)** provides two pulses per revolution of fan. Output is open-collector and main board must have pull-up resistor to 12V.
>
> **Signal Control (PWM)** is input for PWM pulses. Base frequency is 25kHz and it is acceptable from 21kHz to 28kHz. Input has TTL level and includes pull-up resistor to 5V or to 3.3V in new constructions. Signal is not inverted and 100% PWM means maximal revolutions of fan. Motherboard has open-collector type output. This construction guarantee, that with disconnected PWM signal will runs fan with maximum revolutions.

So in theory, you could use a [555](http://www.555-timer-circuits.com/) timer that produces a PWM signal based on a potentiometer input. Or simply anything capable of doing 25kHz PWM.

An example of the *Triple-Five-Timer* being used in such a way below. *(Note that it's not from my head, found it [here](http://weblog.sirajs.com/article/555-timer-based-pwm-power-control-circuit). Hope I didn't mess something up.)* Also note, that I did not bother calculating proper values for that 25kHz operation.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVhQQ9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Basically you adjust the discharge/charge rate of the *C* capacitor by sweeping the *R1* pot. All there is to it. The rest is just use of the 555 magic.

---

That said, I'd consider replacing the transistor. That is IMO the most relevant solution.

Comment: It might help to include a little of the linked page in your answer, in case it ever disappears.  Or perhaps a diagram of how the 555 could be used.

Comment: @David - Yes, it would be helpful to know what's on the other side of the link. Dzarda, I trade that for an upvote.

Comment: Challenge accepted.